# Pytorch lightning saving model during the epoch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I would like to save a checkpoint every time a validation loop ends. I set up the `val_check_interval` to be `0.2` so I have 5 validation loops during each epoch but the checkpoint callback saves the model only at the end of the epoch. I couldn't find an easy (or hard) way to save the model after each validation loop. It seems a bit strange cause I can't see a reason to make the validation loop other then saving a checkpoint.

What is the simplest way of doing that?

Thank you,

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.html)?
Not sure if it exists on your version but, setting `every_n_val_epochs` to 1 should work. If so, it should save your model checkpoint after every validation loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the [lightning docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.html):  `save_on_train_epoch_end` (Optional[bool]) – Whether to run checkpointing at the end of the training epoch. If this is False, then the check runs at the end of the validation.

Using `save_on_train_epoch_end = False` flag in the ModelCheckpoint for callbacks in the trainer should solve this issue.